# How do I use a numerical variable and a loop in automator?

Tags: applescript, automator, preview

Since scripting is not that powerful in case of Preview.app, I am trying to find the solution with Automator. Here's the problem:

I've got a protected pdf file of 130 pages. It happens that I can't print it, but I can save it page by page as jpg file. The problem is when I save it as jpeg, it closes the original file and opens the newly created jpeg file. So the task is pretty much simple (with the proper knowledge of variables and loops).

I need to make a loop, that would open my pdf file with Preview.app, go to page number i, save the document as i&".jpg", wait a second and close Preview.app.

1. I can't find any example of building a loop.
2. The Russian translation is disgusting (and I am not aware of a simple way of making it English once again), which makes the task even harder.
3. I can't find any example of using variables as a parameter of the recorded 'Type' command.

After googling for a while, it looks like the best solution for this simple task  is to do that manually...

Answer (score 1):

Intheory, s.o. could copy [this](https://gist.github.com/M2vH/e8e80ee91e7a43e7e0d3) or [`clone`](https://gist.github.com/e8e80ee91e7a43e7e0d3.git) this file, name it `document.wflow` and put it inside a folder structure like this `/pdfToJpeg.workflow/Contents/document.wflow` and open it in Automator.

This is the structure of a `.workflow` file when you look at Package Content.

This workflow will ask for a file to select, extract any page as pdf, rename each file like `page_01.jpg` and convert it from `pdf` to `jpg`.

Please be patient, its Automator, but you can invoke it step by step from `Automator.app`.

This is how workflow looks like:
[image: pdfToJpg.preview]

Comment: thank you for yout attempt, but I doubt it would work, since when I try to extract and save any page as pdf, I always get a blank pdf (without any content). Moreover, I believe, that it is basicaly a bug, when it allows me to save a page as jpg (I can't print, I can't export, I can't save, but I can save it as jpeg)

Comment: It says that the first and the last actions were of the older version and their behavior might be different. and it doen't know this Bilder aus PDF action... %-(

Comment: @Serjio `Bilder aus PDF` means `Picture from PDF` and is out of a Automator v 2.1.1. Have you tried to open the pdf from a Firefox with pdf plugin? I have tried to secure my pdfs in the past and it always failes when opened with firefox plugin.